# Kendo Dynamic Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I try to create a [dynamic grid](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-generate-model-from-data) based on dummy data first called `dataSourceMatrix`. Grid load fine with dummy data's without any error and display the grid. But when I try to read the data from `kendo dataSource` it display nothing. Both data's return a same result. Any idea why?

[Here a full demo for my situation](https://dojo.telerik.com/iwonoYEN)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have no `dateFields`, so `parseFunction` is undefined, and therefore not callable.

Try this way:

```
parseFunction = function (response) {
    if (dateFields.length >= 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            for (var fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < dateFields.length; fieldIndex++) {
                var record = response[i];
            }
        }
    }
    // console.log(response);
    return response;
};
```

Comment: still the table won't display. Is my  dataSource `dataSourceMatrix` in a right way?

Comment: Basically I want `dataSourceMatrix` will return something like this  `[{"venueName":"Big Room","x":null,"venue_0":"X","venue_1":"X","venue_2":"X","venue_3":"","venue_4":"","venue_5":"X","venue_6":""},...` in console.log